The AddMonths method in C# PersianCalendar doesn't work properly
I wrote the code below and I want to add 4 months to "1402/12/29" and expect it to return "1403/04/31" value, but it returns "1403/4/29".
int persianYear = 1402; 
int persianMonth = 12;   
int persianDay = 29;    

PersianCalendar pc = new PersianCalendar();
DateTime gregorianDate = pc.ToDateTime(persianYear, persianMonth, persianDay, 0, 0, 0, 0);
var newDt =pc.AddMonths(gregorianDate, 4);

int persianYear2 = pc.GetYear(newDt);
int persianMonth2 = pc.GetMonth(newDt);
int persianDay2 = pc.GetDayOfMonth(newDt);

string dt = $"{persianYear2}/{persianMonth2}/{persianDay2}";


Console.WriteLine(dt);


Can you share or include PersianCalendar.cs class in you question please?

@SELA: It's part of .NET.

Ohh thanks... let me check and try to answer @JonSkeet

Why would you expect it to return 1403/04/31? You're adding 4 months to "the 29th of the month" so I'd expect it to still be the 29th of the month. That said, you're adding months in the Gregorian calendar...

@JonSkeet: the 12th month in the Persian calendar has 29 days and the first 6 months have 31 days.

@AlirezaGhalamkari: That doesn't explain your expectation though. If you added 4 months to the 28th, would you expect the result to be the 30th? What about adding 4 months to the 15th? It's unclear why you'd expect the 29th to become the 31st. (Adding 4 months to the 31st could end up on the 29th due to truncation if the target month only has 29 days, but that's different, because then the "natural" result just isn't valid.)

There are two problems here:

Firstly, your way of doing the arithmetic
Secondly, your expectations

You're not adding months in the Persian calendar - you're adding months in the Gregorian calendar, then converting that Gregorian result into the Persian calendar.
DateTime basically doesn't support the idea of "a date in a particular calendar".
You might want to use my Noda Time project, which does support that. Sample code:
using NodaTime;

var start = new LocalDate(1402, 12, 29, CalendarSystem.PersianArithmetic);
var end = start.PlusMonths(4);
Console.WriteLine(end.ToString("uuuu-MM-dd", null));

(PersianArithmetic matches the behavior of PersianCalendar from .NET 4.6 onwards.)
Now, in terms of expectations, adding 4 months to a date that's on the 29th of the month will always give "the 29th of the result month", if that has 29 days. If you were expecting to get the 31st because it's the end of the month, you'd need to specify that explicitly.
So as it happens, your code was already giving you what I'd consider to be the right answer, but not what you expected.
If you want to find out "the end of the month 4 months later than a given month", in Noda Time you'd do this - note the With(DateAdjusters.EndOfMonth):
using NodaTime;

var start = new LocalDate(1402, 12, 29, CalendarSystem.PersianArithmetic);
var end = start.PlusMonths(4).With(DateAdjusters.EndOfMonth);
Console.WriteLine(end.ToString("uuuu-MM-dd", null));

Now the result is 1403-04-31.
